# Things that saved lose when logout

Tags: plugins, php, themes

i been working on theme for my portfolio on my host and domain name

http://alyelgarhy.com/

and things i saved when login changed when logout for example i change the tagline to senior web designer its back to just another word press theme after logout  the many social links in the end of the website i delete some of them when login and i change the map too .
 when logout all what i saved of this three things changed other changes keep saved on both login and logout and any else work just fine

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Are the values actually reset in the database?

Comment: when i deactivate or active plugins its work fine in all why its only with this three stuff

Answer (score 0):

i fix it and yes it was cache problem i download this plugin and its work fine now

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-website-not-updating-right-away/